# Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.web.client.HttpClientErrorException: 404 Not Found] with root cause

Tags: java, spring-boot, client, resttemplate

i am trying to send data to another server from here. simply server side calling and i am very new to this part. i am using RestTemplate to handle client side.
 so i handled my java client side like this:

```
private static void test1()
{
    final String uri = "http://localhost:8888/markClassAssessmentAnswer";

    ClassAssessment classAssessment = new ClassAssessment();
    classAssessment.setAssessmentKeyId(Long.valueOf(67));
    classAssessment.setStudentRecordKey((long) 234);
    classAssessment.setStudentMark(56.3);
    classAssessment.setMarkedBy((long) 56555);
    RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
    ClassAssessment result = restTemplate.postForObject( uri, classAssessment , ClassAssessment.class);
    System.out.println(result);

}
```

all i want is to sent data to the  http://localhost:8888/markClassAssessmentAnswer from localhost:8080 server. but an error occuring, saying

```
"Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.web.client.HttpClientErrorException: 404 Not Found] with root cause

org.springframework.web.client.HttpClientErrorException: 404 Not Found
    at org.springframework.web.client.DefaultResponseErrorHandler.handleError(DefaultResponseErrorHandler.java:85) ~[spring-web-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar:4.3.14.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.handleResponse(RestTemplate.java:708) ~[spring-web-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar:4.3.14.RELEASE]"
```

please help me

Comment: where is your server controller code?

Comment: there are few possible things which may go wrong. check if the service, you are trying to access, is running or not. check the endpoint. check if it requires headers also or not.